# Magnolia rich text fields

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm looking at outputting Rich Text in Magnolia directly to the front-end. I'm defining the field as below:

```
@TabFactory("Content")
public void contentTab(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab) {
    tab.fields(
            cfg.fields.text("title").label("Title"),
            cfg.fields.richText("subtitle").label("Subtitle")
    );
}
```

Within a template, when information is saved into the JCR it appears to encode the data with HTML entities:

```
Title: ${content.title}
Subtitle: ${content.subtitle}
```

Outputs (raw source) ...

```
Title: The Title Field
Subtitle: &lt;p&gt;The Subtitle Field&lt;/p&gt;
```

But should output (raw source) ...

```
Title: The Title Field
Subtitle: <p>The Subtitle Field</p>
```

Is there a way to stop the Rich Text fields from being encoded automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decode function works: 
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/cmsfn#cmsfn-DecodeHTML

```
[#if content.text?has_content]
    ${cmsfn.decode(content).text}
[/#if]
```

Comment: Well, obviously its gonna work but that's not stopping the encoding at the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to find a better approach

Comment: This the standard Magnolia way of outputting html.

Answer (score 0):

Most framework try to get rid of the [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)-kind of attacks so it is a good way to use the template as the following:

```
Title: ${content.title}
Subtitle: <p>${content.subtitle}</p>
```

It will prevent the users (or admins) to run magic JS or some other bad codes on the client.

Back to the question: check out the documentation here https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Component+definition. There is something called **escapeHtml** take a look at it. :)

**Edit:** as [bashaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600240/bashaus) pointed out he was using page properties not components. The solution in this way the following:

```
[#if content.text?has_content]
    ${cmsfn.decode(content).text}
[/#if]
```

**TL.DR:** Try to avoid html characters in dynamic content, but the feature is able to be turned off.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not using components, I'm using page properties for this particular item. Any ideas on how to do it for the property (using the tabs item above)